# Angular JS range input issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

when the all corners range input is moved, the rest of the inputs work fine but when another corner range is moved the all corners move 1~3 pixels, what could be the issue here?

Demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/g10fsxym/

code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

myApp.controller('myAppCtrlr', function($scope) {

```
var allcorners = new Quantity(5);
var topLeft = new Quantity(5);
var topRight = new Quantity(5);
var bottomLeft = new Quantity(5);
var bottomRight = new Quantity(5);

$scope.brCorners = allcorners;
$scope.brTopLeft = topLeft;
$scope.brBottomLeft = bottomLeft;
$scope.brTopRight = topRight;
$scope.brBottomRight = bottomRight;

$scope.brTopLeftCorner = function() {
    $scope.brTopLeft = topLeft;
}
$scope.brBottomLeftCorner = function() {
    $scope.brBottomLeft = bottomLeft;
}
$scope.brTopRightCorner = function() {
    $scope.brTopRight = topRight;
}
$scope.brBottomRightCorner = function() {
    $scope.brBottomRight = bottomRight;
}

$scope.brAllCorners = function() {
    $scope.brTopLeft = $scope.brCorners;
    $scope.brTopRight = $scope.brCorners;
    $scope.brBottomLeft = $scope.brCorners;
    $scope.brBottomRight = $scope.brCorners;
}});
function Quantity(value) {
var qty = value;
this.__defineGetter__("qty", function() {
    return qty;
});
this.__defineSetter__("qty", function(val) {
    val = parseInt(val);
    qty = val;
});}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a copy of `$scope.brCorners` (otherwise you are working with references, so when you change one variable the another is also changed).

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g10fsxym/2/)

```
    $scope.brAllCorners = function() {
      $scope.brTopLeft = angular.copy($scope.brCorners);
      $scope.brTopRight = angular.copy($scope.brCorners);
      $scope.brBottomLeft = angular.copy($scope.brCorners);
      $scope.brBottomRight = angular.copy($scope.brCorners);
    }
```